# Slicing a sparse tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

Currently, sparse tensors don't support indexing, and the tf.sparse_split() operation can't split a sparse tensor according to a given proportion. If I want to select a portion of the training set (which is a sparse tensor) as the validation set, what function should I apply?

Answer (score 0):

As of 0.11 this doesn't seem to be possible: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1588